# Depth system - previous 'top' item flashes upon change

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to set up a depth system of sorts in processing.
The goal is for it to function similar to a (Windows) window.

I have a class called 'Window' and that can take some arguments and it will successfully draw a window that can be dragged around.

The depth system works as it stands right now. I can't click on windows 'under' the current window and if I click on another window, the order of the windows is switched correctly.

The problem is that whenever I switch between windows, the previously selected window flashes (is not drawn) for a frame, and then appears again.

I cannot work out why this happens at all. Here's my code, let me know if you need any further info.

Windows.pde:

```
Window[] wins;
int win_count = 0;
boolean win_drag = false;
int win_selected = 2;

void setup()
{
  size(800, 600);
  wins = new Window[3];
  wins[0] = new Window("Test", 20, 20, 300, 200); 
  wins[1] = new Window("Test 2", 20, 260, 350, 225); 
  wins[2] = new Window("Test 3", 400, 20, 250, 150); 
}

void draw()
{
  background(10);

  for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++)
  {
    wins[i].draw_window();
  }
}


void bringToTop(Window winID)
{
  Window[] new_wins;
  new_wins = new Window[wins.length];

  int win_pos = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++)
  {
    if (wins[i] == winID)
    {
      win_pos = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  arrayCopy(wins, 0, new_wins, 0, win_pos);
  arrayCopy(wins, win_pos + 1, new_wins, win_pos, wins.length - win_pos - 1);
  new_wins[wins.length - 1] = winID;

  arrayCopy(new_wins, wins);
}


boolean isOnTop(Window winID)
{

  int win_pos = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++)
  {
    if (wins[i] == winID)
    {
      win_pos = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  Window[] top_wins;
  top_wins = new Window[wins.length];
  int winTopCount = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++)
  {
    if (mouse_in_rect(wins[i].winX, wins[i].winY, wins[i].winW, wins[i].winH + 24))
    {
      top_wins[winTopCount] = wins[i];
      winTopCount ++;
    }
  }

  int last_real_win = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < top_wins.length; i ++)
  {

    if (top_wins[i] != null)
    {
      last_real_win = i;
    }
  }

  return (wins[win_pos] == top_wins[last_real_win]);
}
```

WindowObj.pde:

```
class Window
{
  String winT;
  int winX;
  int winY;
  int winW;
  int winH;

  boolean dragging;
  int winXOff;
  int winYOff;
  int winTH;
  int my_id;

  Window(String ttl, int WX, int WY, int WW, int WH)
  {
    winT = ttl;
    winX = WX;
    winY = WY;
    winW = WW;
    winH = WH;

    dragging = false;
    winXOff = 0;
    winYOff = 0;
    winTH = 24;
    my_id = win_count ++;
  }

  void draw_window()
  {
    if (win_selected == my_id)
    {
      fill(60);
    }
    else
    {
      fill(40);
    }
    rect(winX, winY, winW, winTH);

    fill(25);
    rect(winX, winY + 24, winW, winH);


    if (dragging == true)
    {
      winX = mouseX + winXOff;
      winY = mouseY + winYOff;


      if (winX < 0)
      {
        winX = 0;
      }

      if (winX > width - winW - 1)
      {
        winX = width - winW - 1;
      }


      if (winY < 0)
      {
        winY = 0;
      }

      if (winY > height - winH - winTH - 1)
      {
        winY = height - winH - winTH - 1;
      }

    }


    Window win_pos = wins[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++)
    {
      if (wins[i].my_id == my_id)
      {
        win_pos = wins[i];
      }
    }

    if (mouse_in_rect(winX, winY, winW, 24) && mousePressed && mouseButton == LEFT && dragging == false && isOnTop(win_pos) && win_drag == false)
    {
      dragging = true;
      winXOff = winX - mouseX;
      winYOff = winY - mouseY;
      win_drag = true;
      win_selected = my_id;
      bringToTop(win_pos);
    }


    if (mouse_in_rect(winX, winY + 24, winW, winH) && mousePressed && mouseButton == LEFT && dragging == false && isOnTop(win_pos) && win_drag == false)
    {
      win_selected = my_id;
      bringToTop(win_pos);
    }


    if (dragging == true)
    {
      if (mouseButton != LEFT)
      {
        win_drag = false;
        dragging = false;
        winXOff = 0;
        winYOff = 0;
      }
    }

  }



}
```

mouseFunctions.pde:

```
boolean mouse_in_rect(int mX, int mY, int mW, int mH)
{
  int but_x = mX;
  int but_y = mY;
  int but_w = mW;
  int but_h = mH;

  if (mouseX > but_x && mouseY > but_y && mouseX < but_x + but_w && mouseY < but_y + but_h)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Howdy Rabbid, it was completely by mistake! Added it back :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused, because you do the calculation of the window order and the drawing in a single loop.
If the position of a window has changed, the drawing of a window may be omitted, while the drawing of an other window is done twice. Note, the index of the windows in the array `wins` changed.

Split the drawing and the update of the windows to 2 separate methods:

```java
class Window
{
    // ...

    void draw_window()
    {
        if (win_selected == my_id)
        {
          fill(60);
        }
        else
        {
          fill(40);
        }
        rect(winX, winY, winW, winTH);

        fill(25);
        rect(winX, winY + 24, winW, winH);
    }

    void update_window()
    {
       if (dragging == true)
       { 
          // ...
       }

       // ...
    }
```

First update the order of the windows and calculate its new position. After that  draw all the windows in a separate loop:

```java
void draw()
{
    background(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++) {
        wins[i].update_window();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i ++) {
        wins[i].draw_window();
    }
}
```